# Why am I getting this error? (Typescript + Express)

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, backend, overloading

I am getting this error:

```
No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
```

for my 3 auth routes. This is my routes file:

```js
import router, { Router, Request, Response } from "express";

import * as authController from "./controllers/AuthController";
import authenticate, { AuthenticatedRequest } from "./middleware/authenticate";

const appRouter: Router = router();

appRouter.post("/auth/login", authController.login);
appRouter.post("/auth/register", authController.register);
appRouter.post("/auth/refresh-token", authController.refreshToken);
appRouter.get("/protected", authenticate, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let user = (req as AuthenticatedRequest).user;
    return res.json(user);
});
export default appRouter;
```

And here is my route function (To big so I had to cut it, only logic inside):

```js
const login = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => { ... });
const register = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => { ... });
const refreshToken = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => { ... });
```

I tried checking the request and response interfaces that my routes used but everything seems ok.

Comment: You are calling appRouter.get with 2 arguments instead of one. The callback must be the first argument, the same way you are doing with appRouter.post, where the first argument is a callback.

Comment: It is a middleware function and has nothing to do with the error. The error is being caused by the 3 post requests.

Comment: If you follow this tutorial when posting a question, will be easier for everyone: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example In your questions, you shouldn't add code that doesn't belong to the problem.